# What is a -d2 flag in docker run command

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am working with a codebase that has a `docker run` command as follows (real name and password removed):

```
docker run -it --rm --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres:11.6 -d2
```

I know that `-d` flag is to `--detach` the container, but what is `-d2`?  I can't figure out the purpose of this flag at the end of the command. I'm also confused why it's at the end of the command and not before the `IMAGE` name like the other flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker command line is order sensitive. Once docker sees an option or flag it cannot parse, it treats that as the image name. And everything after the image name is the command to run instead of the default command. In other words:

```
docker run ${options_to_run} ${image_name} ${command_override}
```

In the postgres image, the entrypoint is `docker-entrypoint.sh` and the default command is `postgres`. That means docker will run this container by default as `docker-entrypoint.sh postgres` (it concatenates the entrypoint and command together into one command with args to run). With the `-d2` command override, that becomes `docker-entrypoint.sh -d2` and the entrypoint script may interpret that as an option to change how it will run. The entrypoint has [special handling for flags](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/38841304ddd06dd3b39cc080b2c8fce5a5be8e52/11/docker-entrypoint.sh#L271-L273):

```
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- postgres "$@"
fi
....
exec "$@"
```

Which means the entrypoint arguments are modified from `-d2` to `postgres -d2` and then the shell in pid 1 is replaced by the command line arguments, `postgres` running with the `-d2` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  `-d2` is a `postgres` CLI option for specifying the debugging level.  We are executing the postgres container with that `postgres` CLI option.

From `postgres --help`:

```
  -d 1-5             debugging level
```